# select2 in laravel doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, laravel, select, drop-down-menu

I want to use select2 in my Laravel but I am having problems with not being able to apply it to my form, how do I do it?

**form.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

   <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
   <link href="{{ asset('css/sb-admin-3.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

@section('title', 'Kegiatan')  
@section('content')

  <link href="{{ asset('css/sb-admin-3.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  
  {{-- Form Input --}}

  <form action="{{ route('admin.kegiatan.store')  }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_tamu" style="font-weight: bold;">Nama Tamu</label>
       <select class="form-control select2" name="id_tamu[]" multiple="multiple">
         @foreach($data2 as $datas2)
          <option value="{{ $datas2->id_tamu }}">{{ $datas2->nama_tamu }}</option>
         @endforeach
       </select>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2()
    })
</script>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vChvQm.png]

How do I fix it? I've done several things but it still doesn't work

Comment: So what does your dev tools say? In app layout, do you have a way to stack your scripts and styles? Maybe jquery isn't loaded

Comment: Why do you load two different select2 ? - remove one of them. I bet you have console errors too. Use `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>` since it is the latest stable version

Comment: So what's the correct way to put together the code? I'm still a beginner